# "Without further adieu" vs "Without further ado"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, confusables

I have just seen an email containing the phrase "Without further adieu"; I always thought it was "Without further ado."

Which is it?

Comment: A recent edit to include a copyright image without attribution has been rolled back. And comments are not the place to discuss voting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The common idiom is, "Without further ado." The words at play here are *ado*:

> fuss, esp. about something that is unimportant

And *adieu*:

> another term for goodbye

Comment: I was getting ready to write just that.

Comment: The point I would also make is that there is nothing at all wrong with deviating from an idiom, if you want.  Maybe in context it's some sort of joke, and why not?

Comment: @z7sg: Good point. I replaced "proper" with "common" to soften the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The word in question is "ado."  It's worth noting that this phrase is nearly universally mis-used by people trying to sound fancy, without understanding its correct context.  The phrase is correctly exclusively used to tie up after a fuss.  People tend to use it as a bland introduction with no apparent cause.

If, for example, you try to give a small speech leading up to something - say, at a wedding or at a gathering of coworkers - and someone interrupts and makes a scene, and is asked to step outside to calm down, then you might re-engage by saying "without further ado, the thing we were about to do."  The usage of the phrase is to brush aside prior mess and explicitly say "okay, we're back on track and there will be no more lead-in."

This phrase is, used appropriately, quite rare.

Comment: Your answer is bang on. You might also mention the reason it is rare is because it is archaic language, even being used in the title to one of Shakespeare's 16th-century plays, [Much Ado About Nothing](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2240)

Comment: I always thought it was like acknowledging that your introduction was not important and basically was a fuss getting in the way of the real content of the event.

Answer (score 3):

"Without further adieu" is a malapropism.

Comment: If it's intended, as most people here seem to think, it's not a 'malapropism' but a pun.

Comment: Indeed, much adieu about nothing.

Comment: While, as a bald statement of fact, this answer might indeed be correct, it could usefully have been expanded to explain *how* it's a malapropism, I think.